# Is require any permissions to open and use it for commercial purpose others web site from android webview

Tags: android

Is it there any rule and regulation on how to use other web site for commercial purpose on our android application  through the webview .
I have developed and music application and now i want to give an search option for user where user can got to music website and download song from within my application only.I don't know how to do this so if is it possible then please give  guide me .

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things :

1. Post a clickable button which redirects to the website link
2. Directly take him to the website link

Both will require use of webviews.